# Visual Studio 2012 - Text editor is missing scroll thumb

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a strange problem with the Text editor in VS Express 2012. Horizontal and Vertical scrollbar in Text editor have no scroll thumb (slider). There are only two directional arrows. All other Windows (Solution Explorer, Properties) work correctly.
I can scroll vertically using mouse, but horizontal scrolling is totally inconvenient, since you can only click on the arow button and move only one character left or right.

Thing i've tried:
   - Disabling / enabling ScrollBars in Options and restarting VS

I have no option to just simply reinstall the App, since i have no Admin rights.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[ScrollBar appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbrnd.png)

Blaz

Answer (score 0):

Clear `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`
in folder

```
%userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Searched from:
[Scroll Bar’s scrolling bar missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294270/scroll-bar-s-scrolling-bar-missing)