# Scroll Bar’s scrolling bar missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Recently in my version of Visual Studio 2012 my scrollbar’s scrolling bar went missing in the code editor(text editor) and I need them back. It’s not the Tools->Options->Text Editor->Display Vertical Scroll bar and Horizontal Scroll bar check box issue. They are both checked and when they are not checked the bar does go away. The arrows in the scroll bar still work and I can move through the code and the page follows the cursor when moving through the code. I checked my other versions of Visual Studios on my computer and the bars are there. 
   [Missing Hbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5oa4.png) [Missing Vbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw0Fg.png)

I tried repairing Visual Studio with no luck. I then tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio also no luck.

Answer (score 18):

Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **All Languages** > **Scroll Bars**

Check the appropriate scroll bars

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. I cleared it up simply by moving the file "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache" from my folder
%userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache.

It appears to have cleared up this "cached" behavior "preference". The neighboring folder 
%userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\11.0\Extensions
had a couple other likely cache file culprits.

Although his solution to delete toolbox*.* files did not work for me, I was inspired by Roman Hnatiuk's resolution of a similar problem at
https://rhnatiuk.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/toolbox-scrollbar-disappeared-in-visual-studio/.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022, I was using a split editor layout (two documents side by side).  The one on the right had its horizontal scroll bar.  The one on the left didn't have one.

Turns out that when I widened the left split pane, the horizontal scroll bar for that pane appeared.  There had apparently not been enough space due to Git commit info in the status bar and the horizontal scroll bar disappeared instead.  Seems like a bug or at least a poorly designed feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and i don't have the path in the answer of Paul Scofield. Yet, i have searched for the ComponentModelCache keyword in my %userprofile% folder and found it as "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\ComponentModelCache". Also found the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache" file in the folder and deleted it. I can see the scroll bar now.

Posting as answer so that it might be usefull for other people like me.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019 (maybe also earlier, didn't check), the vertical scrollbar has two modes: "bar mode" (the usual one) and "map mode" (the one where the code in the file is previewed).

For some reason, I had the "map mode" turned on by default, so I changed to "bar mode" by:

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars -> Use bar mode for vertical scroll`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was simply that the output window had somehow come un-docked. It was positioned where it would be if it was docked at the bottom and it looked right, but it was actually floating over the editor window, covering the horizontal scroll bar. Docked it properly and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as several previous answers, I navigated to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages. In my case, all the options that should have been checked had been checked. I toggled the 'show horizontal scroll bar' and this fixed it for me.